# dojox/form/manager "Tried to register widget" Error

Tags: dojo

**Here is my HTML:**

```
**<form action="http://localhost/so/users/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="user_login_form" id="user_login_form" widgetid="user_login_form" data-dojo-type="dojox/form/Manager">
.
.
.
</form>**
```

**This is my js code **

```
<script="text/javascript">

require(
    ['dijit/registry','dojo/_base/array','dojo/parser','dojo/ready','dijit/form/TextBox','dijit/form/Button','dojox/form/Manager',

    ],
    function(registry,array,parser,ready,textbox,button



    ){
    // parse the dom
    parser.parse();

}); // close the dojo sandbox



</script>
```

**This is the ERROR ON THE CONSOLE**

**DEPRECATED: dojox.form.Manager::getDescendants() is deprecated. Use getChildren() instead. -- will be removed in version: 2.0 kernel.js:203
dojo/parser::parse() error 
Error
arguments: undefined
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "Tried to register widget with id==user_login_form but that id is already registered"
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: undefined
_*proto*_: SetUpError.d**

Comment: This is usually the error you get if there is a widget somewhere else on the page with the same id (user_login_form). Have you double checked that this isn't the case?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following at onLoad() / before the code where you are actually creating the widget:

```
if (dojo.byId('user_login_form') != null) {
                        dojo.forEach(dijit.findWidgets(dojo.byId('user_login_form')), function (w) {
                            w.destroyRecursive();
                        });
                    }
                    dojo.destroy(dojo.byId('user_login_form'));
                    if (dijit.byId('user_login_form')) {


dijit.byId('user_login_form').destroy();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already specify the id, which will be used by the registry, the widgetid seems redundant and might actually cause the error.